# CSS: prevent item lowering with multiple text lines

Tags: css

First of all excuse me if the title is unclear. I dont really know how to describe the problem which also makes it harder for me to google for solutions.

I've inserted my code in a fiddle so I can explain it better:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lzbavyu9/2/

I want the X always to be on the same height as the first line of the text. I've tried things as vertical-align but that doesnt work. It always moves down with the last line of the text.

code is below

```
<div class="panel-title">
  <h3>test sdfjsdf sdjfk sjkdf sdjk fjksd fjskdf jksdfj ksdfjk sfd jksd</h3>
  <span class="collapse-button">
    <i class="pull-right" aria-hidden="true">X</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-title {
  width: 200px;
}

.panel-title h3 {
    margin: 8px 0 -1em 0;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.panel-title span.collapse-button {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
}

.collapse-button i {
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-title {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.panel-title h3 {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}

.panel-title span.collapse-button {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.collapse-button i {
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-title">
  <h3>test sdfjsdf sdjfk sjkdf sdjk fjksd fjskdf jksdfj ksdfjk sfd jksd</h3>
  <span class="collapse-button">
    <i aria-hidden="true">X</i>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="panel-title">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem alias est ex, reiciendis expedita natus distinctio quos ipsam cumque soluta, iusto incidunt molestias mollitia, ullam labore aliquid iure inventore voluptate!</h3>
  <span class="collapse-button">
    <i aria-hidden="true">X</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div h3{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 10em;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>test sdfjsdf sdjfk sjkdf sdjk fjksd fjskdf jksdfj ksdfjk sfd jksd</h3>
  <i>X</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute` on your `.collapse-button` class. Add `position: relative` in your `.panel-title` class. If you want to adjust the position of the **X**, you can change the values of `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom` properties in `.collapse-button` class

```css
.panel-title {
  width: 200px;
}

.panel-title h3 {
    margin: 8px 0 -1em 0;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    position: relative;
}

.panel-title span.collapse-button {
    padding: 0px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
}

.collapse-button i {
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-title">
  <h3>test sdfjsdf sdjfk sjkdf sdjk fjksd fjskdf jksdfj ksdfjk sfd jksd</h3>
  <span class="collapse-button">
    <i class="pull-right" aria-hidden="true">X</i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

> .panel-title {   position: relative;   width: 200px; }

and

> .collapse-button i {   position: absolute;   top: 5px;   right: 0px; }